# How to list the containers that exit before last 10 minutes?

Tags: docker

I tried to list the containers in the docker which was exited before last 10 minutes. But I am unable list by status as it is listing only exited container;

`docker container ls -f 'status=exited'`

I created 3 images and executed all the 3 containers(alpine, tomcat and redis); 
I stopped 2 containers and made one container up and running, then I tried to list the containers which was exited 10 minutes ago but it is not listing properly

`docker container ls -f 'status=exited'`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter based on status code. If exit with status code `0` you can use

```
docker ps -a --filter 'exited=0'

#or if exit with 1

docker ps -a --filter 'exited=1'
```

This will filter all the container that exited with status code or you can filter any container on different status code.

```
docker ps -a --filter 'exited=0' | awk '{print $1 " "   $8 " " $9 " " $10 " " $11 " " $12 }' | grep -E "([1-9]\d|\d{3,})* minutes"
```

This will print container that is exited greater then **10 minutes** ago.

```
docker ps -a --filter 'exited=0' | awk '{print $1 " "   $8 " " $9 " " $10 " " $11 " " $12 }' | grep "weeks \| days \| hours \| hour "
```

this will list all the container that exited hours, days or  weeks ago